# Switch on openbox window manager

Tags: raspbian

I'm using RASPBIAN and I don't really like the default window manager.

How can I uninstall it and switch on openbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed `openbox` (`sudo apt-get install openbox`) and create the `~/.xinitrc` file like this:

```
$ echo "exec openbox-session" > ~/.xinitrc
```

Now, when I run `startx`, the openbox session is started.

Comment: openbox may already be installed.  It is on my Raspbian systems.

Comment: @joan Actually it was... Yes. `:-)` This is my second day using Raspberry PI! I'm so happy with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I too changed my [WM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) (for [i3](https://i3wm.org/), what else?) but I don't want to directly log into it, because I want the comfort of the distro's [DE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) (network, sound control, etc.) so I edited `~/.dmrc`

From this

```
Session=lightdm-xsession
```

To this

```
#Session=lightdm-xsession
Session=i3
```

And logged out and back in.